# Put the c.column_names from the Database into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, associative-array

After I execute the select statement like this 
  and I want to retrieve the fields from the database then fill it and insert it back to the database.

```
$query = "SELECT c.column_name FROM information_schema.columns c";
$query.= " WHERE c.table_name    = '$table' AND c.table_schema  = '$db_name' ORDER BY
c.ordinal_position";
```

then I fetch it into an array , and I tried it so many ways. Here are some of them

1-

```
$x=0;
$y=mysqli_num_rows($result) ;
while ($x<$y){
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$a1=array_fill(0,$y, array_values($row));

$x++;
       };
```

Output : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => age [1] => age ) [1] => Array ( [0] => age [1] => age ) [2] => Array ( [0] => age [1] => age ) )`

and the insert query Looks like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`".implode('`,`', array_values($a1))."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $values)."')";
```

Output : `INSERT INTO table (`Array`,`Array`,`Array`) VALUES('value1','value2')`

2-

```
$x=0;
$y=mysqli_num_rows($result) ;
while ($x<$y){
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$x++;
     };
```

Output : `Array ( [column_name] => age )`

Query Output : `INSERT INTO table (`age`) VALUES('value1','value2')`

And i tried all the basic stuff .

The problem here that the assoc array got only one Key [column_name] and it overwrites it every time I fetch a new record. So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

i fixed the array output but the query didn't work , that's how i call the insert function

```
public function Insert($table,$values,$db_name) {
    global $db;
   $attribute = $this->getcols($table, $db_name);
     // ^^ recives the returned assoc array $row from getcols

   $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`".implode('`,`', array_values($attribute))."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $values)."')";
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: i got the array output done 
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [column_name] => id ) [1] => Array ( [column_name] => name ) [2] => Array ( [column_name] => age ) ) `

but the query output 
still the same 
`INSERT INTO table (`Array`,`Array`,`Array`) VALUES('value1','value2')`

Comment: In case any1 wants to know the answer . 
This is how i figured it out 

   `while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $ret[]=$row['column_name']; //copy the key value i want to another array
          };`

I don't know how i didn't think about that way , but anyway This is the answer gl to every1